# Mocha chai tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha

I want to have a test fail, because the email already exists, so I create duplicate@dave.com and dave@dave.com, but is there a way to do it without this?

```
it('prepare', (done) => {
    chai.request(rest_api_url).post('/subscribers')
        .send({email: 'dave@dave.com', name: 'klaas'})
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
        });
    chai.request(rest_api_url).post('/subscribers')
        .send({email: 'duplicate@dave.com', name: 'klaas'})
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
});

it('it should not edit to email that is duplicate', (done) => {
    chai.request(rest_api_url).put('/subscriber/dave@dave.com')
        .send({email: 'duplicate@dave.com', name: 'klaas'})
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(403);
            done();
        });
});

it('cleanup', (done) => {
    chai.request(rest_api_url).delete('/subscriber/' + 'duplicate@dave.com')
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
        });
    chai.request(rest_api_url).delete('/subscriber/' + 'dave@dave.com')
        .end((err, res) => {
            res.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
});
```

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution, but there are other issues with this code. For one, the unit tests are non-idemponent, so state carries from one test to the next which can lead to very confusing situations and makes the tests difficult to reason about. I'd write an answer with this and other suggestions, but it sounds like you're not asking for general feedback. I'd recommend editing your post to include your question as well as inviting general feedback, and maybe showing the full `describe` block and a bit of context. See [ask].

Comment: @ggorlen Yeah, I never head of idemponent, but I have this problem of creating the duplicate@dave.com sometimes gets excuted after my test. At least this is how it feels when the test sometimes doesn't work. Also the test is slow.

General feedback is welcome.